# When do my privileges take effect

Tags: support, privileges

Just wondering when my privileges will take effect now I've passed 1000 rep. I don't see up/down votes, i still just see one number

Comment: You improve your rep so fast, congratulation man.

Comment: Thanks, been spending waaaay too much time here this week!  ;o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just re-calc'd your rep to verify that it was over 1K, and it is.

I get the impression that you're expecting to see something different on pages with votes, and that's not actually the case. If you take a look at the [privilege page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/view-vote-counts), you see this figure:

[image: show vote figure]

When the page loads, you see the picture on the left. If you click on the vote count, it will *then* display the breakdown.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much